# Variable output empty when executing procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have declared a variable and want to set it's value by way of a select query.

I have a table:

```
fileNameGenerator
-------------------
(pk)fileSymbol | bc
```

Here's my procedure:

```
alter procedure bcSymbol
(
@bc decimal(18,15)
)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
Declare @bcSymbol varchar(50)
Select @bcSymbol = (SELECT fileSymbol From fileNameGenerator WHERE bc = @bc)
RETURN
```

For some reason, this is the output I get...

Running `[dbo].[bcSymbol] ( @bc = 8.550000000000000 )` I get:

```
No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[tempFileName].
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting the proper symbol back. I copied the `bc` value in from the table itself. The output should have been a 1 according to the table.

Comment: sorry about that. sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 4):

All you've done is assigned a variable. You haven't selected it or used it in an output parameter. Similarly, if you do this, what do you expect the output to be? There is no output!

```
DECLARE @x INT = 1;
```

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.bcSymbol -- schema prefix, always
  @bc decimal(18,15),
  @bcSymbol VARCHAR(50) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- why did you comment this out?

  SELECT @bcSymbol = fileSymbol
    FROM dbo.fileNameGenerator -- again, schema prefix
    WHERE bc = @bc;
END
GO
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
DECLARE @bcSymbol VARCHAR(50);
EXEC dbo.bcSymbol @bc = 8.550000000000000, @bcSymbol = @bcSymbol OUTPUT;
PRINT @bcSymbol;
```

What this doesn't handle is the case where there are multiple identical values in the `bc` column. If two rows match the `WHERE` clause, which one do you expect to be assigned to the variable? Please don't say "the first" or "the last" because there is no such thing unless you have very specific criteria.

There are slightly easier ways to do this (and this kind of eliminates the problem, if your client is ready to receive multiple rows in the output), but they have more overhead, e.g. you can just select directly without bothering with any variables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.bcSymbol -- schema prefix, always
  @bc decimal(18,15)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- why did you comment this out?

  SELECT bcSymbol = fileSymbol
    FROM dbo.fileNameGenerator -- again, schema prefix
    WHERE bc = @bc;
END
GO
```

And then the call is simpler (but a little more convoluted in, say, C#):

```
EXEC dbo.bcSymbol @bc = 8.550000000000000;
```

And [here is why you want to not be lazy about schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: thanks very much. we're generating filenames by using several variables, all of which are unique and the only "key" they share is the symbols column. so for instance...if i have a table:

fileSymbol | bc | var1 | var2 ...etc

then the filename is bcsybol + var1symbol +var2symbol... concantenated string. my hope was to return that filename as a string and i have 8 variables.

Comment: @user2369145 this sounds an awful lot like something you'd want to do in the application layer, not in T-SQL. And it's kind of scope creep for this question IMHO, which was, essentially, why does assigning a variable not result in any output?

Comment: sorry about that. my tools are kinda limited and right now i just want to get the thing functioning. the filenames were generated with vlookups similar to this in excel and i'm trying to keep the naming logic similar. the most straightforward way i could think to do this was in an sproc. i've tried making some changes based on your recommendations...now it's asking for input for the output parameter.

Procedure or function 'test' expects parameter '@outputVal', which was not supplied.